# How to get watch time of html5 video in php without any external software?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-video

```
<video id='myVideo' controls autoplay>
    <source src='a.mp4#t=00:00:00' type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

How to get watch time of html5 video in php and store into php variable  without any external softwares?

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your question, you want to know the elapsed time after video started. Here is the solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myvideo").on(
        "timeupdate", 
        function(event){
          onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
        });
    });

    function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime, duration){
        /* Here you can get both currentTIme and duration */
    }
```

Comment: How to store it in php variable

Comment: As your tracking function is in javascript. You can't write php inside js but You can create php file and pass time value as post/get parameter  in ajax request. In php you can use store value in session or in db .